# Connecting points in qqplot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I am trying to plot a `qqplot` graph for different data samples. I am able to draw it for individual data samples. How can I draw a `qqplot` graph for multiple data samples? Also, I want to connect all the points with a line and color for each data set to differentiate them. How can I achieve this in MATLAB?

I am getting the output as below:

[image: my output]

I am trying to get the output in the below format(`qqlplot` for 4 samples).

[image: qqplot for 4 samples]

I am loading the data from csv file into matlab. 
Next, drawing the graph using the function `qqplot(1mb);`

Data Set1:(variable size: `1mb`)

```
379
398
474
541
656
673
684
712
749
751
770
782
788
829
837
864
886
919
935
946
991
993
995
1000
```

DataSet2: (variable size: `512kb`)

```
313
406
443
534
558
561
613
645
649
699
705
732
737
748
752
755
766
774
780
795
796
802
806
823
842
846
872
873
889
904
915
936
966
983
993
```

Comment: Please add your code and some sample data.

Comment: Hi Harre, added the sample data